# ++ increments value by 2 instead of 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using the following reducer to add products, delete them, and add them to a cart. I would like the `'ADD_TO_CART'` action when dispatched to add an item to the cart, but if an item is already in the cart, I would like to increase it by 1. However, the method is increasing cart items by 2 instead of 1

```js
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_PRODUCT':
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [action.payload, ...state.products]
      }

    case 'DELETE_PRODUCT':
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.filter(product => product.id !== action.payload)
      }

    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
      if (state.cart.some(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)) {
        const updatedItemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(cartItem => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)
        let cartItems = [...state.cart]
        let itemToUpdate = cartItems[updatedItemIndex]
        itemToUpdate.quantity++
        return { ...state, cart: cartItems }
      } else {
        const newItem = { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 }
        return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, newItem] }
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This is the code dispatching the action

```js
function addToCart(product) {
  dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
    payload: product
  })
}
```

I am calling the action from the following component

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { ProductContext } from './ProductContext'

export const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  const { deleteProduct, addToCart } = useContext(ProductContext)

  const handleDelete = () => {
    deleteProduct(product.id)
  }

  const handleCart = () => {
    addToCart(product)
  }

  return (
    <div className='product__card'>
      <h3>{product.productName}</h3>
      <p>{product.price}</p>
      <button className='button'>View Product</button>
      <button onClick={handleCart} className='button'>Add to Cart</button>
      <button onClick={handleDelete} className='button'>Delete</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: How are you dispatching the Add to Cart action?

Comment: @AjeetShah I am dispatching it from a context provider and calling the function from a component, I have edited the question to include code for both

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake. You MUTATE your state.

```
        let cartItems = [...state.cart] // <-- reinitialize only the array,
        // the array items remains with the same reference!!!!
        let itemToUpdate = cartItems[updatedItemIndex]
        itemToUpdate.quantity++ // <--- this will mutates your state!!!
        return { ...state, cart: cartItems }
```

Fix: create a new item, and copy the data with the spread operator, and delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the quantity from a number to an empty quote.

```
Old: const newItem = { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 }

New: const newItem = { ...action.payload, quantity: '' }
```

Comment: It still increments by two, but this time the initial quantity is not set, it remains at 0

Comment: What is your initial state value?

Comment: it is an empty array

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into the same problem with a very similar situation, and none of the current answers helped me. Therefore I can only recommend

```
itemToUpdate.quantity++
```

Be changed into

```
itemToUpdate.quantity += 0.5;
```

I know that this is not the correct way to solve this problem, but the functionality works, and you can change it later when you will find the solution

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The issue here is that of a state mutation. The cart array is shallow copied, but the `itemToUpdate` is *still* a reference to the object in the previous state, `itemToUpdate.quantity++` mutates this object reference.

```js
case "ADD_TO_CART":
  if (state.cart.some((cartItem) => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)) {
    const updatedItemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(
      (cartItem) => cartItem.id === action.payload.id
    );
    let cartItems = [...state.cart];
    let itemToUpdate = cartItems[updatedItemIndex];
    itemToUpdate.quantity++;                        // <-- mutation!
    return { ...state, cart: cartItems };
  } else {
    const newItem = { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 };
    return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, newItem] };
  }
```

The reducer function is likely being invoked twice as part of the `React.StrictMode` component's check for [Detecting unexpected side-effects](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

Following is a snippet from the docs, emphasis is mine:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
> can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
> This is done by ***intentionally double-invoking*** the following
> functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, `render`, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or ***`useReducer`***

For the same/similar information in the current docs see [Fixing bugs found by double rendering in development](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development).

## Solution

When updating state, shallow copy all state, ***and nested state***, that is being updated. In addition to shallow copying the `cart` array, the cart item that is being updated should also be shallow copied into a new object reference, *then* override the properties that are being updated.

Example:

```js
case "ADD_TO_CART":
  if (state.cart.some((cartItem) => cartItem.id === action.payload.id)) {
    return {
      ...state,
      cart: state.cart.map((item) =>      // <-- shallow copy cart array
        item.id === action.payload.id
          ? {                             // <-- new cart item object reference
              ...item,                    // <-- shallow copy cart item
              quantity: item.quantity + 1 // <-- update property
            }
          : item
      )
    };
  } else {
    const newItem = { ...action.payload, quantity: 1 };
    return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, newItem] };
  }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image: Edit increments-value-by-2-instead-of-1]

I know Redux isn't used in the code the post, but they have a wonderful doc on the reason for and applying [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) that you should take a look at.